# AoCG2021 Day 21: Blinking through the forest

Tags: code-golf, grid

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2020 Day 3](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/3).

---

On the way to vacation, you're traveling through a forest on an airplane. For some biological and geological reasons, the trees in this forest grow only at the exact integer coordinates on a grid, and the entire forest repeats itself infinitely to the right. For example, if the map (input) looks like this (`#` for trees and `.` for empty spaces):

```
..##.......
#...#...#..
.#....#..#.
..#.#...#.#
.#...##..#.
..#.##.....
.#.#.#....#
.#........#
#.##...#...
#...##....#
.#..#...#.#
```

the forest actually looks like this:

```
..##.........##.........##.........##.........##.........##.......  --->
#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..
.#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#.
..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#
.#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#.
..#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.....  --->
.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#
.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#
#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...
#...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....#
.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#  --->
```

Starting at the top-left corner of this forest and moving at a rational slope (e.g. `3/2` represents two units to the right and 3 units down), how many trees will you encounter until you escape the forest through the bottom row? (You encounter a tree if your path goes through the exact integer coordinates of that tree.)

**Input:** A rectangular grid representing the map, and a rational number (non-zero, non-infinity) representing the slope of your movement. You can use any two distinct values (numbers/chars) to represent trees and empty spaces respectively. You can take two positive integers for the slope instead of a rational number, and the two numbers are guaranteed to be coprime.

**Output:** The number of trees you will encounter during the flight.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Grid:
.##
#.#
##.
down/right -> trees
1/1 -> 0
99/1 -> 0
2/1 -> 1
2/3 -> 1
1/2 -> 2
1/3 -> 2
1/99 -> 2

Grid:
##.#
.###
##..
..##
down/right -> trees
1/1 -> 3
1/2 -> 4
1/3 -> 2
2/3 -> 1
3/4 -> 1

Grid: (the one shown at the top)
down/right -> trees
1/1 -> 2
1/3 -> 7
1/5 -> 3
1/7 -> 4
2/1 -> 2
```

Comment: Could you add a test case where the top left corner contains a tree?

Comment: Can we take the transposition of the grid as input? I.e. an array of columns, instead of an array of rows

Comment: @tjjfvi No, it is not allowed.

Comment: so we need to see the forest for the trees?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/217219/95126)?  (the shortest [Jelly] answer to that transplants directly here...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen The 05AB1E and Charcoal answers as well by the looks of it, so I personally agree with the Duplicate. My dupe vote is a hammer though, so I'll leave this comment instead.

Comment: Huh, for some reason I couldn't find that challenge when I was writing it. I agree that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Should we dupe this one to that one or do reverse?

Comment: This is the more general of the two though...

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

```javascript
(a,x,y)=>a.map((r,i)=>t+=r[i*x/y%r.length]|0,t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZPdaoMwFIDvfYpzM0i2TBPtKG64FxEvQmutw2mxYWtp@@wuwaLiYhIo5CInfpyfj@MX/@HHTVsexGvdbPNul3SIkxM54@ST@9/8gFBLShmIl6RNy@dTcH5q/SqvC7HPrpSIhOKr6H5LsQd0gaItt@@QegApJcDkyYgK5I1OAxXLILthuMinTVMfmyr3q6ZAO6SSEFAMMIwhCIAamDi2MxD2DFtiIgcmHPsJTXksTBwvM/jDu3meRuZd2aDwLneutLfafx/9u1qOHCZfPTC5k2XFrPTMop1x2t7B7ExXcEDn96lXqkPZf7naTEybiblkYtrGZ7Xm/S01roG0hZjZk72cXoFp6VRa86pEA7FeIN6IbW3XxLa0so/Q8CN2fw)

Input an 2d 0/1 array where 1 means tree, and step x, y.

Use the fact that you can index an array with non-integer value without causing errors in JavaScript. You will get non-harmful `undefined` which may be convert to `0` safely by any bitwise operator. And as you are keeping moving south, you may only encounter at most 1 tree each row. So we just sum all tree encountered each row. And that's all we need to make it working.

Answer (score 4):

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), <sup><s>59</s></sup> 57 bytes

```
f=lambda F,a,b,x=0:F[a-1][x%len(F[0])]+f(F[a:],a,b,x+b)?0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVFLasMwEKVbncJIFCyiCLtZtDGIZOVLKFrINP6AqhjbIc5Zusmm9EzNaSp57Ma4ghnePN680Uif35fy2pUne7t9nbt8_fazzYXRH9m7DlKmWcZ6ESWp1OtYyf7ZHG2YykhRtcod0IkCzSqjuwgM7k_7YnJoEyl7ITDB-akJ-qCygVEeGg9b3tam6kxlj21IFaqbynah801EEWKMD4gTggh3QThyBGUxiyl9CNnLoo7ZZl4_jJwTh4M8GAMNwCc3wCfgCfBkxkM3GiTQM_YCHhXkz3-mmTzHBTaLC7_-XwgecvqRXw)

Inputs a 2D array of booleans, and 2 integers.

### Normal Python, 69 bytes

```
f=lambda F,a,b,x=0:F[a-1:]>[]and F[a-1][x%len(F[0])]+f(F[a:],a,b,x+b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVHRasMgFKWvfoUog0itNM3DiuDoy_IT1gdDmy5gbWgySL9lL33Z_mn7mmpusoZWuHLu4ZyjV79-6kv7cfLX6_dnWy7Wv--lcvZY7CzOueUF79RS5touUmnetLF-h_vO6O7F7X2S66VhZl4GYKUBx7xgEPY32xzGtEZq3SlFKClPZ9zhymNnInQRNqKpXdW6yu-bhBlUnyvfJiFVqkNCCNkiQSmiIhQVKBCMpzxl7C7kq4c-5dm0vweFJAELRTAU6kHcwgFxA54CTyc8uFEvAc_gBTwo6H_-RDNmDgNkDxd-fR4IHnL8nRs)

Comment: Why Whython when Python is shorter :P

Comment: @Bubbler Ython?

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 60 bytes

```
f g a b=sum[cycle(g!!(a*t))!!(b*t)|t<-[0..div(length g-1)a]]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JYhBCoMwFAWv8twlJUpCu6wn@fxFtDGGxlBqLBS8e0wtD94MM9v16WIsZYKHxdCv20Ljd4xO@KYR9pKlrBwq93xvSXfdI3xEdMnnGb410jKXxYaEHq93SBliApFRRmllWFH936r9mz7bWZlxxU2WAw)

Takes input as a list of lists, followed by the down and right numbers.  Trees are represented as 1s, blanks spaces are represented by 0s.

Comment: First Haskell answer for AoCG2021!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>11</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) (Avoid multi-link chaining by getting the m-slice result again when needed.)

```
mJ’×⁵‘ị"mS
```

A full program accepting a list of lists of `1`s (trees) and `0`s (clearings), the Down amount, and the Right amount that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/X61HDzMPTHzVufdQw4@HubqXc4P8Pd2/xf7ij6fDy///19JSV9SCAC8SAYi4wA0QoA9lAAiKuDBFXRhKH6OYCK4HogeqFsKEqlOHmI6mBmvnf8L8xAA)**

#### How?

```
mJ’×⁵‘ị"mS - Main Link: Map, Down (Right is the third program argument)
m          - modular slice Map's rows using Down
              -> list of the rows on which we could hit trees
 J         - range of length -> [1, 2, 3, ..., length of slice result]
  ’        - decrement -> [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]
    ⁵      - program's third argument, Right
   ×       - multiply -> [0, Right, 2×Right, ..., (n-1)×Right]
     ‘     - increment -> [1, Right+1, 2×Right+1, ..., (n-1)×Right+1
        m  - modular slice Map's rows using Down
       "   - zip with (f(value, row) for row in m-slice result):
      ị    -   index into that row
         S - sum
```

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217223/95126) seems to be 1 byte shorter.  No idea how it works, though...

Comment: Thanks @DominicvanEssen, changed mine using what saves the byte (getting the result of `m` again when needed to avoid chaining quicks).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes

Expects `(grid, dy, dx)`, where `grid` is a binary matrix.

```javascript
(G,v,h)=>(g=y=>(r=G[y])?r[x%r.length]+g(y+v,x+=h):0)(x=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLbjoIwEIbveYq52aQNo3ZgDUFTveQhSC@Mi6AhYNAQeHpE66EuhTSZZvr1n1N72tW7y746nq@zovxLuoPsWIQ1ZlxuWCrb3lYyilvFt1Xc/FTzPCnSa6bclLVujY0rM74SnDVS8C4CCbEDEINAQgKFD4dQmE7vgnLU2nH2ZXEp82Selyk79GnvGs5hsQAxYGGINMa8t44szB9lhN6TeRbmT7AwtDHe92TO4DEFFOYyZ6IvGPsLCkNFL/uB@tBU0lBJU0oaFvQJauS2FTSA3yFprM@JsP9aGfsbE0@lUWBBS418Cwo0@rX9p2eu7gY)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 29 bytes

```
g@>:2Wy<#g{i+:g@y@xy+:ax+:b}i
```

Full program; takes dy, dx, and each row of the grid as arguments. The grid should use `0` for no tree and `1` for tree. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/3cHOyii80kY5vTpT2yrdodKholLbKrFC2yqpNvP/f0MuYy4DA0NDAwjgAjGgmAvMABGGBiA1UHFDiLghkjhENxdYCUQPVC@EDVVhCDcfSQ3UzP@6RQA)

#### Explanation

```
g@>:2Wy<#g{i+:g@y@xy+:ax+:b}i
                               For our purposes, y, x, & i can be considered to start at 0
g                              List of arguments
 @>:2                          Remove the first two
                               g is now just the grid
     Wy<#g{                }   While y coordinate is less than number of rows in g:
              g@y@x             Get the value (1 or 0) at coordinates (x,y) in g
                                (using cyclical indexing)
           i+:                  Add it to running total i
                   y+:a         Increment y by first program argument
                       x+:b     Increment x by second program argument
                            i  After the loop, autoprint the number of trees encountered
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <strike>57</strike>, 54 bytes (@GB)

```
lambda a,y,x,i=0:sum((r*(i:=i+x))[i-x]for r in a[::y])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBdaoQwFIXpa1ZxSV6SadQ603aKYME1zKPjQ8pUGhh_UAfiWvoilHZP7Wp6r3EGBeOXwznHm3z-tOPw0dTTV5kevy9DGbz8Pp9N9XYyYPSonbbpQ9JfKim7jbRJau-dUrkNXFE2HXRgazB5koyF8um_O5NBCpzzMBQi9A8jWF42Ay0CGRevC6-Lle7TbLb4zJL1vDjErX_lWTpxCkbT5DnHTWjr07uTTgGN7mj0roDbMbKwb892kPxYc1Wwgz9FHMUQvMKWxdGOYI_wRLBD2BM8su3iod9RXU91h3VdwgCsbrCyv8qU4Ap1vGTU7VWPZrHtbD3IUmZ6U5lW4kZLNCqldLPc9DT57z8)

##### Old version

```
lambda a,y,x,i=0:sum(r[(i:=i%len(r)+x)-x]for r in a[::y])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDRasMgFIbZrU9xUAa6mWRpN7oFMsgz9DLNhaUNExITTArmWXYTGNs7bU8zjbZEUD9__vN79POnn8aPTs1fdX74vox19Pr71oj2eBIg-MQNl_lTNlxaqksqs1zeN2dFNXs0LDJV3WnQIBWIMsumivmAvztRQA4Y4zgmJPYDOQgTLeAWYtkuXideJyvdV6PF4mtCrefgILf8lSdk2i6Q66YssT3EUp3OhhoGrnXjWtcV3J5RxEPfyJHig8KsQnv_ijRJIXqHDUqTrYOdhRcHWws7B89oEzzuOhc3uLj9Oi5DAJJ3NnK4yq4CM6vbf7a6vOrJIvZaqpHWtOAPreipPXBqjYwx3oWfnme__wM)

Expects a list of lists of 0s and 1s plus two integers.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I thought of that but `x=y=1` and a taller than wide forest looks like a counter example to me. I think to get this approach right one cannot avoid using a `len` at some point.

Comment: You're right I'm thinking of height * width of forrest :(

Comment: [54 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBdaoQwFIXpa1ZxSV6SadQ603aKYME1zKPjQ8pUGhh_UAfiWvoilHZP7Wp6r3EGBeOXwznHm3z-tOPw0dTTV5kevy9DGbz8Pp9N9XYyYPSonbbpQ9JfKim7jbRJau-dUrkNXFE2HXRgazB5koyF8um_O5NBCpzzMBQi9A8jWF42Ay0CGRevC6-Lle7TbLb4zJL1vDjErX_lWTpxCkbT5DnHTWjr07uTTgGN7mj0roDbMbKwb892kPxYc1Wwgz9FHMUQvMKWxdGOYI_wRLBD2BM8su3iod9RXU91h3VdwgCsbrCyv8qU4Ap1vGTU7VWPZrHtbD3IUmZ6U5lW4kZLNCqldLPc9DT57z8)

Comment: @GB NIce one! I was toying with the idea but couldn't get it to work. Kinda cool that that annoying +x-x can be made to pay for itself that way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 45 bytes

```
(a,b,c)->sum(i=0,(#a-1)/b,a[b*i+1,c*i%#a~+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLBasMwDIbveQrRMnBahVnOxggmfZGQgxLoMKTDdO1hl716ZjuYyqzE2P8n/7@sQzxfXfPp1zP0q2KccK6b0/f9olyvUe25ofp1Qh6mgzsSzgf3suffI431ygQ9DBoJyRLqtIdzrNjEiwShmAz5EnXgVAm2dstvBi0/m7k4rRY@yrvNJL1kJT/zihftIy/6F689qmWa/s37rEMx2VhV7P3yoxiaE/ir@7oFuYuwg5mXRZ0RuK4RhoEJIa4xQNRdJ8CUus06otCy3nUJjOhqRMCIgBFNo0B4S7oV2Vb4N/0u9EfWadDww/wB)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ιнε³N*è}O
```

-6 bytes, by using the exact same program as [*@ovs*' used in the related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217224/52210).. :/ (thanks for letting me know *@DominicVanEssen*)

Takes the inputs in the order \$right\$, \$grid\$, \$down\$, where \$grid\$ is a matrix of `0` for empty spots and `1` for trees.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M4Le89tPbTZT@vwilr///8NuaKjDXQMdAyB0AAZxupEw0RQaKC4AZJaQxgJFofwkdUboqg3xKHeEMVehClI9qDZiyyOaoYhFvdjNwfVnbFcxgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFqim16UmaJQUJRaUlKpW1CUmVeSmmKloKRTeaTd5dBuHS4lx@SS0sQchUy4YqCs/aOGeXrKxY@a1gRnH1qpw5VQrBSUmZ5Roluck1@QaqVweL@1Qkp@eR6Cr6TDVXloWULYoXXF/8/tvLD33NZIP63DK2r9/yv5l5YAjQaZqnNom/3/6OhoJT1lZSUdJWU9MKmspxSrY6hjGKujgFXK0hK3nBE@KWNcUoY6Rril8OiytITIKUOEgUqgsnogHkgHkkfwKzIiRpExYUVGxCgy1jGBekoPJAEGYM8B@RAM1qkHYStDdULllGFyyihyyjBTwAoheuGmwHhQdcpI9qGohNmAHP@D2InGg9@JpoPfieaD3YmgQiUWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ι          # Uninterleave the second (implicit) input-matrix with the first (implicit)
           # input right-slope as step-size
 н         # Only leave the first inner matrix
  ε        # Map over each row:
   ³       #  Take the third input down-slope
    N*     #  Multiply it by the 0-based map-index
      è    #  Use it to 0-based modular index into the row
  }        # After the map:
   O       # Sum the list together to get the amount of trees encountered
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: [6 bytes shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217224/95126)...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks. Hadn't even looked at the related challenge.. Funny how it's literally the EXACT same. :/

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>56 ...</s> 51 bytes

```ruby
->v,y,x{z=0;v.each_slice(y).sum{|l,|(l*z+=x)[z-x]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3dCsIgHMXv9xShBKv@k2ZXEu5FRGKObQUORrahmz67reg2bw4cfufjOSkXOx6LagYHdl34@TqTtm7uN6MfTZu7AzHTsHoNPtfH5cTtQSyFlSHEnheVAQtu7YQhQz1uKa@Jcq/2Z5VXexrCJyNDlmXjrhcCEYwRIEy@igmSUEIpE5Cx/5SmqhQuqV2agokmY9tpfAM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 80 bytes

```rust
|i:&[Vec<_>],a,b|i.iter().step_by(b).fold((0,0),|(x,t),v|(x+a,t+v[x%v.len()])).1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLbbuIwEH33VxishXFrWQVaVS2ln7EvNEIm66iW3JDGhkIbvp36tqyDulbszBnPnJmxTrs19lTV@E2oGij@QtgtLS2u8OLUqcfR8rcsn1bPBRNs3SmurGyBcmNls1ofYE15tdF/AG7YDWUd7JmlbOf@14LZ691y/2vHtXTMBaV8cvLk81Ci2rQYVN1sLcOlMNJQrGo8WiIYckIQ4W4TPmR4J8vBMqTAhGH3uToRPjz08TTASQZnGXRXzjPN4KwPPZ3HhdswJL4D10logyPuzJ@amfXpb/9Df9GLs28jjMU8O48LeSNtFAx/kNBB8pPoJ5k/ZqMQEnNSbrRTBDnzZzGJ86fhLh7rPoN3/dHvs9Gn59yCBk@RVOVX06ra6noAw6@jKxkEQOfn66CKA8N7hkVtPmQbVBH0kZH8lWjIfsReoFGkz3gRndw0WlkYv9Rjyt9EA53uNC9fRWsgOcoOysViTMYUC4O3Rn1KysuN1rK0QDNz3qubD8DCDK7Xw0WQMEa2diXfB1DBKKn8ygVeHag70mj/co4onkd0@gY)

Takes input as a slice of vectors of ones and zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 298 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,N=[]>=T extends N["length"]?N:a<T,[...N,{}]>;type b<T,N>=N extends[{},...infer M]?T extends[infer A,...infer U]?b<[...U,A],M>:0:T;type M<G,Y,X,N=[],>=G extends[]?N["length"]:M<{[K in keyof G]:b<G[K],a<X>>}extends[...a<Y>,...infer Rest]?Rest:[],Y,X,G[0][0]extends 1?[...N,0]:N>
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAQwB4AVAGgDkBeAbQF0A+W8w9AD3HUQBNIhavQBEAG17xwACxGMA-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-Ry-nK5n69nuPTsc3S8nW7XKeX8ZP24nW8v+5PaYvS-vN8PO5ex43j4TSYf183qfn39Pb4fhmr4gXu2ZGmUEp5v2OqFo2BqjuyZqwZSXZNj2EFQWO5YoYQ9rVph5CtjhlYAOwEXaUF9iRlryt2opAA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// Convert a number literal to a tuple of {} of equal length
type NumToTopTuple<T,N=[]> = T extends N["length"] ? N : NumToTopTuple<T,[...N,{}]>

// Cycles a non-empty tuple T to the left N times
type CycleLeft<T, N> = N extends [{}, ...infer M] ? T extends [infer A, ...infer U] ? CycleLeft<[...U,A],M> : 0 : T

type Main<
  Grid,
  Y,
  X,
  Trees=[],
> =
  Grid extends []
    // If there are no more rows left, return Trees
    ? Trees["length"]
    // Otherwise, recurse:
    : Main<
      // Map over Grid and cycle its rows X times to the left. Then, remove the first Y rows
      {
        [K in keyof Grid]: CycleLeft<Grid[K], NumToTopTuple<X>>
      } extends [...NumToTopTuple<Y>, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : [],
      Y,
      X,
      // If there's a tree at (0,0), increment Trees
      Grid[0][0] extends 1 ? [...Trees, 0] : Trees
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 68 bytes

```r
function(g,d,r,n=1:(nrow(g)/d)-1)sum(g[1+cbind(n*d,(n*r)%%ncol(g))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDhigIhFIX/@xShBN5dm8WpJVjwSab50Y4lQt1ZrsbS00@aUgpejh/nHOTSgpFOp2CW8w2n6GeUTllFCo3@kUjzv3TwZWGjIdyu0g36c/r1aCV@WJUGwXqN03xJLhhhceStYbzrhOjKYVnUy54iD5F0GoWLwkXDS5o9LSVTs0VXh3j1N57ayZkzUQZ//bv4870/Eh3vMkQK6R3fIn9Y8QNyGAY9jopzAGO44MDKYtI6tNKwEqu@JdtM9i35zmTbkn0muzfpa8/yAA)

**Ungolfed**

```r
ntrees=function(g,d,r)  # ntrees = function with arguments
                        # g = grid, d = down, r = right
 n=1:(nrow(g)/d)-1      # first calculate n = 0 ... number of moves we'll make
                        # (number of moves is rounded-down to an integer)
 sum(                   # now calculate the sum of all trees 
  g[                    # at positions of g given by
   1+                   # 1+ = R uses 1-based indexing
    cbind(              # cbind = combind 2 vectors, to use as 2d indices to a matrix
     n*d,               # x-coordinates are just d * n
     (n*r)%%ncol(g))])  # y-coordinates are r * n, modulo the number of columns in g
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 84 bytes:

```
f=lambda b,d,r,y=1,x=1:0if y-1>=len(b)else(b[y-1][(x-1)%len(b[0])]+f(b,d,r,d+y,r+x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLdCoIwFMfve4rdhBseYaeIMlgvMnah6Cgwk@WFPr1piZg7fYwDO/z2P1/bqrY@38rtoXJdZ1WRXNMsYSlk4KBVCI3Co7xY1kZ4UkVe8lTkxT3nqe6J0byJUKyfXEsjTGj5KzYLW3BhI0Rnby6/10wxrSUgoAGNIMe994xZVe5S1tzyl3QQCbGEcUzRDQ23PkTYUJBUxvFEg@h9BWL1NhDrDZ8mfTPA9PyE8AeJ9OJx7oySCftZkMiCv7Mg0e6iyrIvul1PQpbAb/fyqxA19H8f58Mb7yi4//DDugc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷＳ⊞υιＩ№Ｅ✂υ⁰Ｌυθ§ι×ηκ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNDsIgEIX3nILIBhJs1G1XxlUTNU3qBbCSQqT0D9Tb41CqKckMb958b2olxroTJoTC9t5dfXuXIx1YjtazgvmttJGYznblRm0byhgu/aSo51gDUYLp6ElM0DoP8iJ6Whldy0jsOD5L2zjAGccD1NEV9iE/VHN8062cqOL4yRhsNmQDfx7CAe1RlhGSpYeiWArNIjaSRWbxSfLJyk9pNCMps2STXgjyv79ifjfD9mW@) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the slope as two positive integers `y` and `x`.

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the grid.

```
Ｉ№Ｅ✂υ⁰Ｌυθ§ι×ηκ#
```

Take every `y`th element of the grid, and from those rows, take every `x`th element respectively. Count how many of them are `#`s.

Comment: 21 bytes by using your exact† answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217220/52210)? _†: well, almost exact.. The integer inputs are in reversed order._

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The grid size is hard-coded in that answer.